# sublime text editor setup problem for c++ language

Tags: windows, sublimetext

when i execute a program this here is shown
[a pic of what is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqoO6.png)
'C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\code/main.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

i tried some methods online but nothing worked.

Comment: did you build it? is that the name? is the location correct? What does your build look like?

Comment: Your forward slash before `main.exe` is causing your problem. Remove it, and try to run `main.exe` without it.